# How can I visualize my csv data into cluster

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I want to visualize my csv data into cluster.

This is my csv data.(https://github.com/soma11soma11/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/challenge2/soma11soma/challenge2/analysis/Soma/total_watt.csv)

For your infomation.
I could visualzie the csv data into 3D graph.

And this is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d



MY_FILE = 'total_watt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['datetime', 'consumption'])

df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [x.time() for x in df['datetime']]

pv = df.pivot(index='time', columns='date', values='consumption')

# to avoid holes in the surface
pv = pv.fillna(0.0)

xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:len(pv),0:len(pv.columns)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf=ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, pv.values, cmap='jet', cstride=1, rstride=1)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

dates = [x.strftime('%m-%d') for x in pv.columns]
times = [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in pv.index]

ax.set_title('Energy consumptions Clusters', color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_xlabel('time', color='darkturquoise')
ax.set_ylabel('date(year 2011)', color='darkturquoise')
ax.set_zlabel('energy consumption', color='darkturquoise')
ax.set_xticks(xx[::10,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(times[::10], color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::10])
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::10], color='lightseagreen')

ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black')

plt.show()


#Thanks for reading! Looking forward to the Skype Interview.
```

And this is the graph, I got from this code.

[image]

I think I should change some points of this code, in order to cluster the data into three group: high, medium and low energy consumption.

The image I want to get from clustering the data is like this.(2D, 3colours.)

[image]

k-means????? should I use?..

Comment: Please edit your title into something more meaningful rather than a commentary

Comment: I too would like to have such nice clusters of my data ...

Comment: From looking at your data I would try some cluster with radial basis functions e.g SVC from sklearn. BTW. There is a nice flowsheet: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the result using `KMeans`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


MY_FILE = '/home/Jian/Downloads/total_watt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['datetime', 'consumption'])

df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [x.time() for x in df['datetime']]

stacked = df.pivot(index='time', columns='date', values='consumption').fillna(0).stack()


# do unsupervised clustering
# =============================================
estimator = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
X = stacked.values.reshape(len(stacked), 1)
cluster = estimator.fit_predict(X)

# check the mean value of each cluster
X[cluster==0].mean()  # Out[53]: 324.73175293698534
X[cluster==1].mean()  # Out[54]: 6320.8504071851467
X[cluster==2].mean()  # Out[55]: 1831.1473140192766


# plotting
# =============================================

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
x = stacked.index.labels[0]
y = stacked.index.labels[1]
ax.scatter(x[cluster==0], y[cluster==0], label='mean: {}'.format(X[cluster==0].mean()), c='g', alpha=0.8)
ax.scatter(x[cluster==1], y[cluster==1], label='mean: {}'.format(X[cluster==1].mean()), c='r', alpha=0.8)
ax.scatter(x[cluster==2], y[cluster==2], label='mean: {}'.format(X[cluster==2].mean()), c='b', alpha=0.8)
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But it does not work

The error message is ; (DataVizProj)Soma-Suzuki:Soma Suzuki$ python 4.clusters.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.clusters.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
ImportError: No module named sklearn.cluster

Comment: I reinstalled sklean and It worked successfullt!! Thank you  very much!!

Comment: What is ""mean 324....., mean,,,6320........ and mean 1831.,,,,,,,,,, by the way!?!?!?

Comment: @SuzukiSoma That's the mean level of your consumption for each cluster. You can rename them in `label=` if you want.

Comment: So it means if the consumption is close to 1831... the points will be blue, the consumption is close to 3247,... the points will be green, and if the consumption is close to 6320, points will be red. ???

Comment: awsome! I admire you... how can I write this code in 10 minutes..........Ichoose your answer

Comment: How you set 1831, 3247, and 6320? or Computers automatically caluculated?

Comment: Do you have some idea how to cluster it with 3D graph!?!??